# About places to live

Tags: difference, word-difference

What's  the difference between townhouses, and country house? 
what's  the difference between country,downtown, village, town
And the last question is why "in" only goes at the first sentence: I live in a mansion - I live on a ranch

Comment: I think the first question can be answered using a dictionary. Did you try any?

Comment: Yes, I did..even I have a dictionary in my cellphone but I didn't  get yet...but just looking at the words I think the first one is located in the town ( ciudad) and the second one in the country ( campo, interior)...

Comment: Please one question per posting. On the last one, a *mansion* is enclosed, a *ranch* is not (open air, ground below and sky above).

Answer (score 2):

> townhouse

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [wisegeek.com](http://images.wisegeek.com/townhouses-on-sunny-street.jpg))</sub>

> country house

[here http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/us/country-house-24.jpg](http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/us/country-house-24.jpg)


It is possible to have townhouses in the country, usually in a village in the country.

The distinction between

> city
>   town
>   village
>   hamlet

are determined by the number of people living there.

You can live

> in a townhouse
>   in a country house
>   in a ranch house
>   in an apartment
>   in a good neighbourhood
>   in poverty

and you can live

> on a ranch
>   on a coastline
>   on a mountain
>   on a boat
>   on welfare

Answer (score 2):

These terms are often very particular to countries and to eras of time. Imagine being a reader absorbed in a Jane Austin novel, or a Sherlock Holmes Story, or a Raymond Chandler detective adventure. Further, being a reader who is familiar with the terminologies of the relevant times and places. Then a simple one or two word phrase such as "country house" or "cottage" paints a picture not only of the building itself but also the surroundings and the (at least for British readers of British stories) the social class of the people living there.

For example: Jane Austen novel, early 1800s, Country House: residence of a wealthy or aristocratic family (Mr Darcy), large house, many rooms, extensive grounds, lake (for Mr Darcy to emerge from), butler, cooks, maids, servants. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_country_house). Such a family may well also have a **Town House** for use when they return to London.

That concept of Town House, would be less common in a more modern setting where it may well simply imply a small-footprint terraced house in an urban setting (be it town or city) - land is expensive so keep area small, build up.

To understand the set of implications of even simple words such as **cottage**, **brownstone**, **mock-tudor semi**, **condo**, or **almshouse** requires quite extensive background knowledge. My general approach is to look up in a dictionary to get a feel for the idea and then keep reading, often additional description comes later.